# View AWS Instance

Tags: image, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have AWS, with a website currently running on it. I want to duplicate that site, for testing purposed, so I created a AMI, and then created a new instance. But, I am unable to hit the IP address and view the site in its copied state. I was able to log onto the server and I verified that all the required files were included when I duplicated the instance.

Is there something else I need to do in order to view the new site? I have tried to assign a dedicated IP address. I have looked everywhere and I can't figure out why I can't view the site.

Comment: Did u check the security groups and rules ? Any error messages when u view in browser ?

Comment: @Sisyphus That fixed it. I didn't realize that I had to set specific security permissions. If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system and type of webserver?  You webserver's config may have it listening to a specific IP address (hint: not the new one your new instance has).  If you have your webserver bind to 0.0.0.0 then it should listen on all interfaces... however, this is all dependent on which web server you're using and conjecture.

I would start by using nmap on the server to see if there's any process listening to port 80 (or whichever port your webserver is using).  Then, I'd check to see if that port was open externally.

Comment: It's a Linux Ubuntu webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You should check a few things -

- Run `netstat -tnl` and look for whatever port you're running the web server on (80 or 443 probably). If it's not listening then your web server isn't running
- If you do see the port, try hitting it locally on the box. `curl localhost:<port>`. If you see your site that way but not at the public IP then you know it's some security group/firewall problem
- Try to just connect to the public IP and port from an outside host. Try `nc -v -z <ipaddress> <port>`, it should say connected. If it doesn't, but the web server is running, you probably need to open the port through the firewall.
- Check the security group that the host is in and make sure your port is allowed
- Check `iptables -L` and make sure that the IP and port isn't blocked there either.